# Read .txt file and copy/paste certain data to Excel meeting certain condition

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

File `sample.txt`:

```
something  
------
--------
------

xyz

12 34 56
78 90 10
11 12 1ds3
14 15 16 17

abc

something  
------
--------
------

xyz

14 34 566
785 490 10
113 142 1ds3
143 155 616 17

abc
```

Now I want to write a VBScript to read `sample.txt` and copy only those data that fall between `xyz` and `abc`.

I tried the following:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim strMerge As String
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile("filepath", ForReading, False)
    Do While txtStream.AtEndOfStream <> True
        If InStr(txtStream.ReadLine, "xyz") <> 0 Then
            strMerge = strMerge & txtStream.ReadLine

            Do While Not InStr(txtStream.ReadLine, "abc") <> 0
                strMerge = strMerge + txtStream.ReadLine
            Loop
        Else
            strMerge = strMerge & txtStream.ReadLine
        End If
    Next i
    Loop
    MsgBox (strMerge)
    txtStream.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, the line "strMerge = strMerge & txtStream.ReadLine" line is executed in both situations: weither the "InStr(txtStream.ReadLine, "xyz") <> 0" is true or False.

Comment: Your text says VBScript, but your code is actually VBA, so which of the two languages is it? They're not the same. Also, you "tried the following" ... *and?* Please describe as exactly as possible what you want the code to do, and how the actual behavior differs from what you expected. Include all error messages you're getting. Do you want the sections between `xyz` and `abc` as a single string? An array? Something else entirely? What do you want to do with the data once you have it? Should it be returned? (you need a function instead of a sub for that) Written to a file?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution using RegEx**

```
Sub test1()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim strMerge As String
    Dim txtStream  As Variant
    Dim textLine As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.txt", ForReading, False)
    txt = txtStream.ReadAll

    Dim objRegEx, oRegResults
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "xyz\s*([\S\s]*?)\s*?\S*?abc"
    End With

    Set oRegResults = objRegEx.Execute(txt)
    For Each txtMatch In oRegResults
        MsgBox txtMatch.Submatches(0)
    Next
    txtStream.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to read XYZ nor ABC here you go.

```
Sub test1()

Dim ReadEn As Boolean
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim strMerge As String
Dim tStr As String
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\projects\sample.txt", ForReading, False)

ReadEn = False
Do While txtStream.AtEndOfStream <> True

   tStr = txtStream.ReadLine

   If InStr(tStr, "abc") > 0 Then ReadEn = False

   ' do not read "xyz"
   If ReadEn Then
      strMerge = strMerge & tStr & Chr(13)
   End If

   If InStr(tStr, "xyz") > 0 Then ReadEn = True

Loop

MsgBox (strMerge)
txtStream.Close

End Sub
```

I switch on ReadEn to enable reading the file to `tStr` I don't `ReadLine` because I may past the EOF while still in the loop. 
Not sure if you wanted to read blanks as well, but they will be read and output. If you want to output `xyz` and `abc` sawp the location of their if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

there was:

- a `next i` not  "in scope"
- `Readline()` handling skipped every two lines of txt file

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim strMerge As String
    Dim txtStream  As Variant
    Dim textLine As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set txtStream =    fso.OpenTextFile("filepath", ForReading, False)
    Do While txtStream.AtEndOfStream <> True
        textLine = txtStream.ReadLine
        If InStr(textLine, "xyz") <> 0 Then
            textLine = txtStream.ReadLine
            Do While Not InStr(textLine, "abc") <> 0
                strMerge = strMerge & textLine
                textLine = txtStream.ReadLine
           Loop
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox strMerge
    txtStream.Close
End Sub
```

of course you have to change "filepath" to a string contianing the actual full path of the desired txt file

Comment: @Nuke, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use some disposable objects and well placed splits.

```
Sub test1()
    Dim ecA, ec(): ReDim ec(0)
    ecA = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\testenv\test.txt", 1).ReadAll, "xyz")
    For I = 1 To UBound(ecA): ec(UBound(ec)) = Split(ecA(I), "abc")(0): ReDim Preserve ec(UBound(ec) + 1): Next
    ReDim Preserve ec(UBound(ec) - 1)
End Sub
```